# How to make a separate element-dict out of bs4.element.Tag list?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scrapped a webpage where I saved a `defaultdict` named `ecg_machines['City'] = []` with `<li>`-elements as elements in list and are of `type <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`. For example I have an element`ecg_machines['Delhi'][0] =`

```
<li class="lst lst_cl mft2 img llc " data-catid="" data-city="New Delhi" data-csttypnm="LEADER" data-csttypwgt="149" data-dispid="3374118533" data-glid="4291542" data-mcatid="" data-modref="2" data-state="Delhi" id="LST1"><div class="clz"><p class="pnt"><a class="pnm ldf cur" href="http://www.goodhealthinc.in/digital-ecg-machine.html#digital-3-channel-ecg-machine" target="_blank" title="">Digital 3 Channel ECG Machine</a></p><a class="ribn NP-1 " id="1imgenq"><div class="bg rib"></div><div class="nor_i imwd"><img alt="Digital 3 Channel ECG Machine" data-limg="//4.imimg.com/data4/JC/MY/MY-4291542/digital-3-channel-ecg-machine-500x500.jpg" id="bu1" src="//4.imimg.com/data4/JC/MY/MY-4291542/digital-3-channel-ecg-machine-250x250.jpg"/></div></a><div class="lstw"><div class="ldc"><p class="desc des_p" id="trimmed_desc1"><b>Application</b>:  Resting &amp; Diagnostic<br><b>Brand</b>:  Allied Medical<br><b>Types</b>:  3-Lead,  12-Lead<br><b>Operation Mode</b>:  Portable<br><b>Channel</b> <a class="wh mlin" href="http://www.goodhealthinc.in/digital-ecg-machine.html#digital-3-channel-ecg-machine" target="_blank"> more..</a></br></br></br></br></p><div class="prc NP-1" id="1prcenq">Rs 31,500/<span class="quan"> Piece</span></div></div></div></div><div class="spro"><div class="nsim"><span><img alt="Digital ECG Machine" data-modref="2" data-prc="Rs 31,500/ Unit" data-slimg="//4.imimg.com/data4/PI/DK/MY-4291542/digital-ecg-machine-500x500.jpg" id="rp1_1" src="//4.imimg.com/data4/PI/DK/MY-4291542/digital-ecg-machine-125x125.jpg" title="Digital ECG Machine"/></span></div><div class="nsim"><span><img alt="Automatic Digital ECG Machine" data-modref="2" data-prc="Rs 68,000/ Unit" data-slimg="//4.imimg.com/data4/PC/RT/MY-4291542/automatic-digital-ecg-machine-500x500.jpg" id="rp1_2" src="//4.imimg.com/data4/PC/RT/MY-4291542/automatic-digital-ecg-machine-125x125.jpg" title="Automatic Digital ECG Machine"/></span></div><div class="nsim"><span><img alt="Digital Twelve Channel ECG Machine" data-modref="2" data-prc="Rs 68,000/ Piece" data-slimg="//4.imimg.com/data4/TA/NW/MY-4291542/digital-twelve-channel-ecg-machine-500x500.jpg" id="rp1_3" src="//4.imimg.com/data4/TA/NW/MY-4291542/digital-twelve-channel-ecg-machine-125x125.jpg" title="Digital Twelve Channel ECG Machine"/></span></div></div><div class="nes"><span class="cnm cmcl"><span><a class="lcname" href="http://www.goodhealthinc.in/" target="_blank">Goodhealth Inc.</a></span><span class="vcom"></span><span class="td t_v cur"><span class="bg t_se" data-val="goodhealth"><span class="ttl wd2 doff" id="tool-tip_n1"><span class="twrw"><span></span></span><span class="t_ts"> </span></span></span></span></span><div class="clg" data-rlocation="Jhandewalan">Jhandewalan, New Delhi<span class="srad cty-t" id="citytt1"><span>201, D. D. A. Commercial Complex, C. M. 1 Jhandewalan Extension,<br> </br></span><span class="ct_l">New Delhi </span><span> - </span><span>110055</span><span>, </span><span>Delhi</span><span><br/></span></span></div></div></li>
```

which reads like

Digital 3 Channel ECG Machine

**Application**:  Resting & Diagnostic
**Brand**:  Allied Medical
**Types**:  3-Lead,  12-Lead
**Operation Mode**:  Portable
**Channel**  more..Rs 31,500/ PieceGoodhealth Inc. Jhandewalan, New Delhi201, D. D. A. Commercial Complex, C. M. 1 Jhandewalan Extension,
 New Delhi  - 110055, Delhi

how can I create a dict out of it like `ecg_machines['Delhi'][0] = {'Name':'Digital 3 Channel ECG Machine', 'Application': 'Resting & Diagnostic', 'Brand': 'Allied Medical', 'Types': '3-Lead, 12-Lead', 'Operation Mode': 'Portable', 'Price':'Rs 31,500/ Piece'...}`

Comment: use `item.find()`/ `item.find_all()` to get inner tags and `item.text` to get text from tag.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am still messing around with the scrapped data, lets see if it works out.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `find()`, `find_all()`, `selec()`, `select_one()` (etc.) to get elements from `bs4.element.Tag`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<li class="lst lst_cl mft2 img llc " data-catid="" data-city="New Delhi" data-csttypnm="LEADER" data-csttypwgt="149" data-dispid="3374118533" data-glid="4291542" data-mcatid="" data-modref="2" data-state="Delhi" id="LST1"><div class="clz"><p class="pnt"><a class="pnm ldf cur" href="http://www.goodhealthinc.in/digital-ecg-machine.html#digital-3-channel-ecg-machine" target="_blank" title="">Digital 3 Channel ECG Machine</a></p><a class="ribn NP-1 " id="1imgenq"><div class="bg rib"></div><div class="nor_i imwd"><img alt="Digital 3 Channel ECG Machine" data-limg="//4.imimg.com/data4/JC/MY/MY-4291542/digital-3-channel-ecg-machine-500x500.jpg" id="bu1" src="//4.imimg.com/data4/JC/MY/MY-4291542/digital-3-channel-ecg-machine-250x250.jpg"/></div></a><div class="lstw"><div class="ldc"><p class="desc des_p" id="trimmed_desc1"><b>Application</b>:  Resting &amp; Diagnostic<br><b>Brand</b>:  Allied Medical<br><b>Types</b>:  3-Lead,  12-Lead<br><b>Operation Mode</b>:  Portable<br><b>Channel</b> <a class="wh mlin" href="http://www.goodhealthinc.in/digital-ecg-machine.html#digital-3-channel-ecg-machine" target="_blank"> more..</a></br></br></br></br></p><div class="prc NP-1" id="1prcenq">Rs 31,500/<span class="quan"> Piece</span></div></div></div></div><div class="spro"><div class="nsim"><span><img alt="Digital ECG Machine" data-modref="2" data-prc="Rs 31,500/ Unit" data-slimg="//4.imimg.com/data4/PI/DK/MY-4291542/digital-ecg-machine-500x500.jpg" id="rp1_1" src="//4.imimg.com/data4/PI/DK/MY-4291542/digital-ecg-machine-125x125.jpg" title="Digital ECG Machine"/></span></div><div class="nsim"><span><img alt="Automatic Digital ECG Machine" data-modref="2" data-prc="Rs 68,000/ Unit" data-slimg="//4.imimg.com/data4/PC/RT/MY-4291542/automatic-digital-ecg-machine-500x500.jpg" id="rp1_2" src="//4.imimg.com/data4/PC/RT/MY-4291542/automatic-digital-ecg-machine-125x125.jpg" title="Automatic Digital ECG Machine"/></span></div><div class="nsim"><span><img alt="Digital Twelve Channel ECG Machine" data-modref="2" data-prc="Rs 68,000/ Piece" data-slimg="//4.imimg.com/data4/TA/NW/MY-4291542/digital-twelve-channel-ecg-machine-500x500.jpg" id="rp1_3" src="//4.imimg.com/data4/TA/NW/MY-4291542/digital-twelve-channel-ecg-machine-125x125.jpg" title="Digital Twelve Channel ECG Machine"/></span></div></div><div class="nes"><span class="cnm cmcl"><span><a class="lcname" href="http://www.goodhealthinc.in/" target="_blank">Goodhealth Inc.</a></span><span class="vcom"></span><span class="td t_v cur"><span class="bg t_se" data-val="goodhealth"><span class="ttl wd2 doff" id="tool-tip_n1"><span class="twrw"><span></span></span><span class="t_ts"> </span></span></span></span></span><div class="clg" data-rlocation="Jhandewalan">Jhandewalan, New Delhi<span class="srad cty-t" id="citytt1"><span>201, D. D. A. Commercial Complex, C. M. 1 Jhandewalan Extension,<br> </br></span><span class="ct_l">New Delhi </span><span> - </span><span>110055</span><span>, </span><span>Delhi</span><span><br/></span></span></div></div></li>'

result = {}

html = html.replace('<br>', '\n')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#print(soup.prettify())

name = soup.find('a', {'class': "pnm ldf cur"}).text
result['Name'] = name
print('Name:', name)
print('---')

items = soup.find('p', {'id': "trimmed_desc1"}).text
items = items.strip().split('\n')
for item in items:
    #print(item)
    parts = item.split(':')
    if len(parts) > 1:
        key = parts[0].strip()
        value = parts[1].strip()
        result[key] = value
        print('key:', key)
        print('value:', value)
        print('---')

price = soup.find('div', {'id': "1prcenq"}).text
result['Price'] = price
print('price:', price)
print('---')

print('result:', result)
print('---')
```

Result:

```
Name: Digital 3 Channel ECG Machine
---
key: Application
value: Resting & Diagnostic
---
key: Brand
value: Allied Medical
---
key: Types
value: 3-Lead,  12-Lead
---
key: Operation Mode
value: Portable
---
price: Rs 31,500/ Piece
---
result: {'Name': 'Digital 3 Channel ECG Machine', 'Application': 'Resting & Diagnostic', 'Brand': 'Allied Medical', 'Types': '3-Lead,  12-Lead', 'Operation Mode': 'Portable', 'Price': 'Rs 31,500/ Piece'}
---
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me the implementation. I feel let down of myself that I couldn't do this much of task on my own. Thanks a ton again. :)